# LibreOffice basic get all checkboxes

Tags: macros, gnu, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I'm currently working on a project that involves migrating VBA macros to LibreOffice Basic macros. However, I've encountered a challenge with one particular macro where I need to iterate over all checkboxes. The problem is, I'm not sure how to retrieve all these elements. Is there a specific function or method available for this task?

Best regards

Comment: Are the checkboxes in a dialog, or on a form in Calc perhaps? It would be nice to see some related LO Basic code (please, no VBA) to give context.

Comment: If you are completely transferring the project to Calc, then perhaps it makes sense to [**abandon checkboxes as controls**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/is-there-still-no-easy-way-to-make-a-cell-a-checkbox/62020/4?u=johnsun)?